# Variant of the cutting-stock problem in Mathematica

Tags: performance-tuning, functional-style

I'm pretty new to *Mathematica* and am trying to learn to solve problems in a functional way. The problem I was solving was to list the ways in which I could sum elements from a list (with repetitions), so the sum is less-than-or-equal to some value. The code below solves my problem just fine.

```
i = {7.25, 7.75, 15, 19, 22};
m = 22;
getSum[l_List, n_List] := Total[Thread[{l, n}] /. {x_, y_} -> x y];
t = Prepend[Map[Range[0, Floor[m/#]] &, i], List];
Outer @@ %;
Flatten[%, ArrayDepth[%] - 2];
Map[{#, getSum[i, #]} &, %];
DeleteCases[%, {_, x_} /; x > m || x == 0];
TableForm[Flatten /@ SortBy[%, Last], 0, TableHeadings -> {None, Append[i, "Total"]}]
```

However, the code checks a lot of unneccesary cases, which could be a problem if `m` is bigger or the list is longer. My question is simply: what would be the most *Mathematica*-esque way to solve this problem with regard to both efficiency and code elegance.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution based on linked lists and recursion:

```
ClearAll[toLinkedList];
toLinkedList[x_List] := Fold[{#2, #1} &, {}, Reverse@x];

ClearAll[getCombs];
getCombs[l_List, lim_Integer] :=
  Cases[
    getCombs[{}, toLinkedList[Reverse@Sort@l], lim],
    getCombs[acc : Except[{}], __] :> Flatten[acc],
    Infinity
  ];
getCombs[accum_, l : {head_, tail_List}, lim_?Positive] :=
  {
     If[lim >= head, getCombs[{accum, head}, l, lim - head], Sequence @@ {}],
     getCombs[accum, tail, lim]
  };
```

The way it works is to create a tree by going backwards, subtracting a given element from the current maximal for the sum, to get the maximal for the sums of remaining elements. The case of repetitions is accounted for by the line `If[lim>=head,...]`.
The resulting numbers are also accumulated in linked lists (`accum` parameter), and finally they are found with `Cases` and converted back to normal lists using `Flatten`. In this way, we avoid unnecessary array copying, so this code should be reasonably efficient.

Here is an example of use:

```
i = {7.25, 7.75, 15, 19, 22};
m = 22;

getCombs[i, m]

(* 
   {{22}, {19}, {15}, {7.75, 7.75}, {7.75, 7.25}, {7.75}, 
   {7.25, 7.25, 7.25}, {7.25, 7.25}, {7.25}} 
*)
```

Note that I did not make an effort to make this function tail-recursive, which possibly can be achieved with some more work. Note also that I did not attempt to optimize the algorithm further, which is probably possible too.

Comment: I like this answer. Today I learned about the concept of tail-recursion :)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thanks. But keep in mind that the above function is *not* tail-recursive, and besides, tail-recursion in Mathematica has [its own peculiarities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481301/tail-call-optimization-in-mathematica/4627671#4627671)

Answer (score 4):

As it is a knapsack problem you could use integer linear programming. The `Reduce` function is applicable for this task.

Here we set up the parameter values and constraints.

```
lens = {7.25, 7.75, 15, 19, 22};
max = 22;
coeffs = Array[v, Length[lens]];
c1 = Map[# >= 0 &, coeffs];
c2 = Total[coeffs] >= 1;
c3 = coeffs.Rationalize[lens] <= max;
```

Now solve and sort by values of objective.

```
solns = coeffs /. {ToRules[
     Reduce[Join[c1, {c2, c3}], coeffs, Integers]]};
SortBy[solns, #.lens &]

(* {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 
  0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}} *)
```